# Marklogic Security Setup not done via cloud init

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to setup a single MarkLogic node in AWS. The image is build using Packer, and setting variables/starting the service is done in the user data of the EC2

Marklogic variables are set like this:

```
MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD=some-password
MARKLOGIC_EC2_HOST=1
MARKLOGIC_MANAGED_NODE=0
MARKLOGIC_DATA_DIR=/data
```

They are then saved to /etc/marklogic.conf.

After that the EBS volume where MarkLogic is going to be is mounted, and Marklogic service is started.

When the server is running, I can see that the variables are in the /etc/marklogic.conf file are correct. The logs show that the user data script runs to the end, and MarkLogic is started.
The volume also appears to be mounted correctly.

When I go to port 8001 on the server, I expect the Security Setup to have been done already.
However, first there is a "Join a cluster" screen, which I skip, and then it asks to do the security setup.

To me, it looks like some MarkLogic variables are not picked up during the setup.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: what version of MarkLogic are you using? If less than 10.0-6, you may need to try with a more recent version. There were some issues identified and addressed with sourcing that conf file during startup.

Comment: @MadsHansen it's 10.0.-8. Where can I find the description of these issues, please?

Comment: Checked it with Marklogic version 10.0.-7.3 and the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

When MARKLOGIC_MANAGED_NODE=0, then cloud-init will not do the server security initialization. The recommendation would be to use the Admin REST endpoints to do the server initialization as part of the startup.

https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/POST/admin/v1/instance-admin